# How do I bring my activity to the front using broadcastReceiver onReceive()?

Tags: android

All of this has to do with my own app.

I have two cases. First, my activity is on top, and everything works fine. My service broadcasts info and my activity updates its GUI.

My problem is that I don't know how to bring my activity to the front if its not already there. Ideally, all the activities in front of it would be closed and this one be brought to the front. How do i do this?

```
broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //what code do I put here to bring this activity to the front and close all other activities on top of it?
        }
    };
```

Here is how I solved the problem with the help of the post bellow.

```
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            i.setClass(MyClass.this, MyClass.class);
            startActivity(i);
```

Comment: When you say "all the activities in front of it" do you mean other activities of your own app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there isn't a direct command to bring an activity to front such as myActivity.bringToFront. Instead you will have to let android do it for you through the intents mechanism.

So if you want to bring an activity to front you will have to call startActivity and pass an intent with the correct flags. For example the flag [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) will do your job. However there is a catch, you cannot set this flag if you use startActivity from within a broadcast receiver or a service. So in your case I think that you should use the flag [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK).

Here is an example:

```
Intent i = null;
i = new Intent(context, My_activity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you very much! I was already on the correct tract when you posted this. But it helped me along.